How to filter and count relation items in typeorm with loadRelationCountAndMap?
I have got an order service in my project. The entities look like this.
@Entity({ name: 'wechat' })
export class WechatEntity extends TimestampedEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn({ name: 'open_id' })
  openId: string

  @OneToMany(() => OrderEntity, order => order.wechat, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  orders: Relation<OrderEntity[]>
}

@Entity({ name: 'order' })
export class OrderEntity extends TimestampedEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string
  
  @Column({ type: 'tinyint', nullable: true, default: 1 })
  status: number

  @ManyToOne(() => WechatEntity)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'open_id' })
  wechat: Relation<WechatEntity>
}

export abstract class TimestampedEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'created_at' })
  createdAt: Date

  @UpdateDateColumn({ name: 'updated_at' })
  updatedAt: Date
}

The classes, Wechat and Order, are entities with one-to-many relations as you can see in the entity declaration and are working properly with the MySQL database.
I want to find all the wechat objects with the number of valid order less than 5.
I try to use .loadRelationCountAndMap to count but not work.
like this
const queryBuilder = this.wechatRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('wechat')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('wechat.orders', 'orders')
  .loadRelationCountAndMap(
    'wechat.orderCount',
    'wechat.orders',
  )
console.log(await queryBuilder.getOne())

I tried to use .getSql() to view the generated SQL statement and found that adding the .loadRelationCountAndMap() statement did not make any difference.
I'm not sure if there are any other methods available to meet my requirements.
Any help would be appreciated.
The app is made with the NestJs framework and all the code is written in typescript.
Thank you in advance.
